# Is there a way in Python to create a for loop that doesn't wait for the code inside to complete before iterating again?

Tags: python, loops, time

Say i have a for loop with a time.sleep function inside

```
import time

list = [1, 2, 3]

for i in list:
    FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i)
```

Is there a way for me to make the loop iterate over every part of the list simultaneously instead of waiting for the code inside the loop to be executed?

Basically the execution order needs to be like this:

```
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(1)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(2)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(3)
time.sleep(3)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(1)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(2)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(3)
```

Instead of this:

```
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(1)
time.sleep(3)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(1)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(2)
time.sleep(3)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(2)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(3)
time.sleep(3)
FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(3)
```

Comment: Unless you are looking for threading or multiprocessing, why not just write 2 loops, with a call to `time.sleep(3)` between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested for loop:

```
for _ in range(10):     # how many times do these 3 function calls happen?
    for idx in range(3):
        FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(idx)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer is much simpler than i anticipated :D

Answer (score 2):

Please be more clear in your questioning, you are currently using the same function name to describe (presumably) 2 different functions.

Also using hard coded timing to wait for completion generally isn't a good idea.

You could just use 2 for loops to get the abovementioned result.

```
import time

list1 = [1, 2, 3]

for i in list1:
    timeRelFunction1(i)

time.sleep(3)

for i in list1:
    timeRelFunction2(i)
```

Also using `list` as a variable name here isn't the proper way since it is a [built-in class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

*Edit according to comment:*

You could try using something like this, check the stock prices every 3 seconds for `n` times

```
import time

list1 = [1, 2, 3]

def stockPriceEveryThreeSeconds(number_of_repetitions):
    for i in range(number_of_repetitions):
        for i in list1:
            getStockPrices(i)
        time.sleep(3)

stockPriceEveryThreeSeconds(2)
```

The above code will check the stockprice every 3 seconds, 2 times.

Comment: It is the same function, that's the entire point. For example, if this function gets the price of stock 1, and it needs to get it again in 3 seconds it will have a different output. I want to be able to get the price of stock 1, 2, and 3. Wait 3 seconds, and get the three prices again.

Comment: See my edit. But as said earlier, please be more concise when asking a question. Everybody is willing to help and put in effort, but saying that stuff was to be supposed that way after the fact shows the lack of a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
import time

list = [1, 2, 3]

for i in list:
    FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i)

time.sleep(3)

for i in list:    
    FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question I'm reading you're looking for a bit of concurrency on list operations. There are a few ways to go about this, and the most optimal is by far the most complex. But an easy way to get started is with the *threading module*. You could modify the following code in this manner:

**From:**

```
import time

list = [1, 2, 3]

for i in list:
    FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i)
```

**To:**

```
def functionThatThreads(numberOfLoops):
    import time
    import threading
    list = [1, 2, 3]

    for _ in range(numberOfLoops):
        for i in list:
            threading.Thread(target=FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated, args=(i,)).start()
        time.sleep(3)

def FunctionThatDoesSomethingTimeRelated(i):
    print(i)

functionThatThreads(2)
```

**Output:**

```
 python .\testing.py
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

This will ensure that the execution order is maintained (first in first executed), while the output will be first finished, first served. Hopefully I answered the question, or this helps!